# How to compare positions of elements in Selenium WebDriver using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, selenium-webdriver

I have an element on a page that acts as a button that reveals a drop-down menu. There are a lot of moving parts on the page and before a few bug fixes the alignment of the menu would be off by a few pixels with the button. I was wondering how to write a test for this as these positions can change. For example:

```
$this->verifyElementPositionLeft($button,348);
$this->verifyElementPositionLeft($menu,348);
```

would not work. What I would like to try to do would look something like the following:

```
$this->storeElementPositionLeft($button,'buttonLeft');
$this->storeElementPositionLeft($menu,'menuLeft');
$this->assertEquals($buttonLeft,$menuLeft);
```

But I must not be understanding the way in which SeleniumTestCase.php stores variables and upon further investigation, these variables are stored as javascript variables and not PHP; is that correct? Any help understanding how to make this work, or direction to more illustrative documentation is much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, I failed to mention that I'm using the phpunit API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking through the code I was able to figure out how this is done, via the SeleniumRC command getElementPositionLeft. Thus:

```
$buttonLeft = $this->getElementPositionLeft( $button );
$menuLeft   = $this->getElementPositionLeft( $menu );
$this->assertEquals( $buttonLeft, $menuLeft );
```

[phpunit-selenium / PHPUnit / Extensions / SeleniumTestCase / Driver.php](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/Driver.php)